# Flutter overlay design widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

[Overlay](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HykFW.png)

Here's a widget that I hope will slide from bottom to top, whilst darkening the page behind it. Any ideas on how I could start this?

Comment: Jack you must have to show some code which you have tried so far anyways you can achive this by using https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showModalBottomSheet.html

Comment: This UI can be achieved using showModalBottomSheet on click of some button in parent UI. To set custom height use SizedBox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a bottomsheet

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text(_title)),
        body: const MyStatelessWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyStatelessWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyStatelessWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: ElevatedButton(
        child: const Text('showModalBottomSheet'),
        onPressed: () {
          showModalBottomSheet<void>(
            context: context,
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return Container(
                height: 200,
                color: Colors.amber,
                child: Center(
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      const Text('Modal BottomSheet'),
                      ElevatedButton(
                        child: const Text('Close BottomSheet'),
                        onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Check this link for reference
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showModalBottomSheet.html